# React navigation v2, how to hide material tab navigators on specific screens?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

## Background

I am building a react native app and using react navigation. I have just upgraded form 1 to 2 and am in the process of changing my TabNavigators to MaterialTabNavigators.

## What I have tried

I cannot find the place in the documentation that tells you how to hide a Material tab navigator on a specific tab. I have tried using

```
navigationOptions: {
    tabBarVisible: false
}
```

But this only works for the regular tab navigators.

## Question

How do I hide the tab bar on specific tabs in the MaterialTabBarNavigator?

Comment: I am also having the same issues, have anyone figured this out by any chance?